# Flex MX datagrid merge columns with a separator

Tags: apache-flex, merge, datagrid, mxml

I have a data grid that has regular columns and merged columns. The columns which are merged, displays data multi-line with a line Separator.

I want it to be displayed like this
Name/DOB( Name and below it DOB with a separator) in one cell as header. A line separator between Name and DOB.

The data will be placed under the header the same way(Name and DOB below with a line separator).

```
Name

DOB

-------------------------

John Doe

10 Sep 1990

--------------------

Jack Jill

9 Aug 1992

---------------------
```

and so on. How can I achieve this?

If I have to extend the data grid component, please explain how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use item renderers to achieve this, The column in which you have two rows will have to have item renderer.

For one [example](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?363694-DataGrid-amp-Item-Renderer) try to create something like that, but, your renderer will be like below. If this does not work, search for **custom item renderer** there are a lot of tutorials on that.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Col 2" dataField="col2">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <mx:VBox horizontalAlign="right">
                <mx:Label text = "{data.text}"/>
                <mx:Label text = "{data.dob}"/>
            </mx:Box>
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```